# UITextView text scrolls up on return key?

Tags: objective-c, uitextview

I placed UITextView into UIScrollView on my View. Then I set focus to UITextView and keyboard appears. I added some text after that I press return key and text inside UITextView goes up but I expect that cursor should go to the next string?? Why so happen?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the `UITextView` to **`resignFirstResponder`**. This will dismiss the keyboard instead of acting as a **return** key.

Comment: I need multiline text. This is couse I use UITextView. See edited post.

Comment: `UITextView` inherits from `UIScrollView`. I am not sure what you are trying to accomplish. If you want the cursor to go to another `UITextView`, then call `becomeFirstResponder` on the next view.

Comment: I need to add text like Office Word do it. Imagine, I enter text, hit press key, input text cursor should go to the next row. But for now, text goes up and not visible. Input cursor stay as was.

Comment: As your cursor advances downward to add new lines, the text above the cursor must go up. What would you like the text to do besides go up as new lines are added?

Comment: On start editing cursor stays on the top of the TextView, after I added new line, text(which I added) goes up and doesn't visible. Cursor stays at the top of the TextView, but I think cursor should jump to the next string and text should not move up outside of the visible TextView area.

Comment: what is the height of your textview?